# What is i4jdel.exe doing in EXE4J-wrapped java-applications?

Tags: java, exe4j

If I run a java-application wrapped in EXE4J to make native Windows app then on the startup it will create and run an executable called `i4jdel.exe` from within user's temp-folder.  Unfortunately, some antiviruses classify this program as malware.

What this `i4jdel.exe` is really about?  What does it do, and, most importantly, are there any official sources confirming its genuineness?

Comment: http://forum.serviio.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=18595

Comment: http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/i4jdel-exe/12983551